# Manually control apollo server cache

Tags: caching, apollo, apollo-server

Is it possible to manually control the cache in Apollo Server?

I want to be able to configure the server to fetch data once, and then forever cache the following requests until I manually tell it to invalidate the cache and fetch new data the next time the same request is made.

I tried using Memory Cache and Redis cache, but I could not find any docs or examples that do what I want. I know how to set TTL or maxAge, but not how to manually control it.

Comment: what about https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching#configuring-reads-and-writes ?